# NumbersFormatException in Array List

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, numberformatexception

I am attempting to put employee details from a CSV file(in the form of FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth,SSN,Role,Salary,Zip,Phone) with salary being an int. The only problem is, each time I try and implement this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.*;


public class Driver {

    //Delimiters used in the CSV file
    private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try
        {
            //Reading the csv file
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.csv"));

            //Create List for holding Employee objects
            List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            String line = "";
            //Read to skip the header
            br.readLine();
            //Reading from the second line
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String[] employeeDetails = line.split(",");

                //Save the employee details in Employee object
                Employee emp = new Employee(employeeDetails[0],employeeDetails[1],
                employeeDetails[2],
                employeeDetails[3],
                employeeDetails[4],
                Integer.parseInt(employeeDetails[5]),
                employeeDetails[6],
                employeeDetails[7]);
                empList.add(emp);
            }
            for(int i = 0;i<empList.size();i++){
                System.out.println(empList);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                br.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ie){
                System.out.println("Error occured while closing the BufferedReader");
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a NumbersFormatException error. An employee class has been made with constructors setters and getters.

I just scanned the CSV. There is always a salary which is the root of my confusion.

Comment: Obviously `employeeDetails[5]` is not always a number.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Well I would like to perform calculations with the salaries and that is where I'm stuck

Comment: What if there is no salary available?

Comment: Is the salary always an integer ? can it be a double ? is it formatted (i.e. 1,000) ?

Comment: I just scanned the CSV there is always a number there

Comment: In blank format 5-6 digit numbers without a comma or anything

Comment: print `employeeDetails[5]` to standard output before you try to convert it into an integer, this way you'll see exactly on which input you're failing.

Comment: It's your word vs. the JRE's. I'll take the JRE's, unless you can provide a [mcve].

Comment: employeeDetails[5] MUST be String not an integer , as you are using Integer.parseInt().

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that:  **Integer.parseInt(employeeDetails[5])**

dosen't fail. So **employeeDetails[5]** must be a String that can be converted to int.

Like: "5", "123", "567"